# How to quickly add content in a new line at end of file?

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

I often have to add stuff at the end of a file, hence I go to the last line:

```
:$
```

yet this is at the beginning of the line. Often I discover myself doing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> to jump by word until I am at the end of the line.

Then I enter insert mode us via `a`, and hit Enter and do whatever I need there.

This feels overcomplicated. How to add content at the end of the file?

Bonus point if I can do it by just one command.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### If file is already opened in normal mode

Use:

```
Go
```

- `G` goes to the end of the file
- `o` enters insert mode on a line below the current one

### If you are opening the file from the command line

You can open vim on the last line of a file from the command line using:

```
vim + filename
```

The `+` lets to specify the line number. Leaving it blank defaults to the last line of the file as explained in the man page:

```
       +[num]      For the first file the cursor will be  positioned  on  line
                   "num".   If "num" is missing, the cursor will be positioned
                   on the last line.
```

Then you can use `o` as above to enter insert mode on the line below.

### What about inserting at the top of the file (or an arbitrary line number)?

In normal mode `gg` can be used to jump to any line in the file by number. So `5gg` jumps to line 5. gg without a number is a shortcut for the first line of the file.

If you wanted to insert a line above the first line, you could do that with:

`ggO`

Comment: I assume that there would also be a key to enter insert mode above current line, isn't there?

Comment: That would be `O`.  (shift-o)

Comment: @Alex Follow up question cause you blew my mind! http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/what-options-are-there-to-enter-insert-mode

Comment: @Alex If you want to expand your answer, please do so via edit. Comments are for meta-purpose (clarification, random side questions) and should not hide valuable information.

Comment: Good point! I've moved my expansion from the comment to the answer.

Comment: The first thing you say about `gg` is true for `G` as well; `5G` will jump to line 5, just as `5gg` does.  It's interesting that `gg` defaults to `1gg` (= `1G`) while `G` defaults to the last line.

Answer (score 4):

- `:$` jumps to the end of the file
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> # enters insert mode at end of
  current line
- Enter # inserts new line

This gets rids of the word by word navigation.