# What options are there to enter insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I used to enter insert mode by `a` never realizing that there is a system as to *where* the insert mode starts.

I was sometimes annoyed that `a` would put the cursor after the first character of a line, yet the thing is: It enters the insert mode *after* the current cursor position.

Then I realized I could enter insert mode at the end of the line using `A`, or below the current line using `o`.

What are the ways in normal mode to enter insert mode and what is their difference?

Comment: `:h inserting` - also `:h replacing`

Comment: @VanLaser You can add that as an answer ^^

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Entering insert mode at different locations

The vim help documents have a great section on this: `:help inserting`

A quick summary is:

- `i`: Insert before the cursor.
- `I`: Insert before the first non-blank character of the line.
- `a`: Insert after the cursor.
- `A`: Insert at the end of the line.
- `o`: Begin a new line below the current line and insert.
- `O`: Begin a new line above the current and insert.
- `gI`: Insert at column 1 of the line.
- `gi`: Insert where insert mode was last stopped.

Insert commands take a count as well, so you can type `3itest<space><esc>` to get:

```
test test test
```

Insert commands can be repeated with `.` as well, so `itest<space><esc>..` will yield (because the `i` inserts before the cursor, which is on the space):

```
testtesttest
```

Finally, I'll add
[EvergreenTree's](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/865/evergreentree) answer
from the comments: You can enter insert mode with `:star[tinsert][!]` which
works like `i` unless you give it the option `!`, in which case it works like
`A`.

### Modifying text and then entering insert mode

It is also possible to modify the text in normal mode and enter insert mode at
the end. See `:help replacing`. A summary of the commands are as follows:

- `c`: Delete text (and yank to the buffer) and enter insert mode.
- `cc`: Delete the line and enter insert mode.
- `C`: Delete until the end of the line and enter insert mode.
- `s`: Delete a number of characters and enter insert mode.
- `S`: Delete a number of line and enter insert mode.

Many of these also work on visually selected text.